# Образовать третий вектор из общих элементов двух разных векторов

Tags: c++, массивы

С формированием массивов все окей, но с построением третьего массива из общих элементов — никак.

```
int* SUM(int* arr, int size,int ARR1, int ARR2)
{

    int a = 0, b = 0, i = 0, j, k;
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < a; j++)
                if (ARR1[i] == ARR2[j])
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < b; k++)
                        if (SUM[k] == ARR1[i]) break;
                    if (k == b) { SUM[b] = ARR1[i]; b++; }
                }
        if (b < 1) cout << "\nТретiй вектор не сформовано";
        else {
            cout << "\nКоординати третього вектора мають вид\nC(";
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
                cout << SUM[i] << ";";

            return (0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Как минимум вы передаете не массивы, а целые числа `ARR1` и `ARR2`...

Comment: и давайте нормальные имена переменным

Comment: а размер массивов? также передавайте

Comment: Что-то странное... Первый параметр функции нигде не используется, вместо массивов целые числа... Странный внутренний цикл по `k`... Кажется, я не понимаю, что Вы пытались сделать....

Comment: прийдеться за вас сделать

Comment: а массивы ARR1 и ARR2 могут быть по размерам разные?

Comment: кстати, вы можете потсавить стрелочку вверх)

Comment: Конечно што да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нате Вам, не мучтесь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
   
int* SUM(int* arr, int* ARR1, int size2, int* ARR2, int size3, int& new_size)
{
    int new_size1 = (size2 > size3) ? size2 : size3;
    arr = new int[new_size1];

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < new_size1; j++)
        {
            if (ARR1[i] == ARR2[j])
            {
                arr[new_size] = ARR1[i];
                ++new_size;
            }
        }
    }

    return  arr;
}


int main()
{
    int new_size = 0;
    int arr1[] = { 1,2,3,0 }; // массив для объеденения общих данных
    int arr2[] = { 3,2,1,8,0}; // массив для объеденения общих данных
    int* dest = nullptr; // сюда будем результат класть
  

    dest = SUM(dest, arr1, 4, arr2, 5, new_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
    {
        cout << dest[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

## Для автора:

Вот реализовал то, что Вам надо:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int* SUM(int* arr, int* ARR1, int size2, int* ARR2, int size3, int& new_size)
{
    int new_size1 = (size2 > size3) ? size2 : size3;
    arr = new int[new_size1];

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < new_size1; j++)
        {
            if (ARR1[i] == ARR2[j])
            {
                arr[new_size] = ARR1[i];
                ++new_size;
            }
        }
    }
    return  arr;
}

int* input_array(int* arr, int& size)
{
    cout << "Quantity of elements - ";
    int quant;
    cin >> quant;
    arr = new int[size=quant];

    for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        cout << "#" << i + 1 << " = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
int* random_array(int* arr, int& size)
{
    cout << "Quantity of elements - ";
    int quant;
    cin >> quant;
    arr = new int[size=quant];

    for (int i = 0; i < quant; ++i) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << "#" << i << " = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int new_size = 0, size1, size2;

    int* arr1 = nullptr; 
    arr1 =  input_array(arr1, size1); // массив для объеденения общих данных

    int* arr2 = nullptr;
    arr2= random_array(arr2, size2); // массив для объеденения общих данных



   
    int* dest = nullptr; // сюда будем результат класть


    dest = SUM(dest, arr1, size1, arr2, size2, new_size);

    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "General elements : ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
    {
        cout << dest[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123336/discussion-on-answer-by-------).